# how OPC Ua Server Reads the signal(data) from the machine

Tags: automation, opc, opc-ua

I am new to OPC UA so my question might be stupid, sorry for that.

exploring OPC UA, I developed an OPC UA server, for that I was doing the simulation for all the nodes defined in the server,

now I need to write the server for the physical machine where I need to read the machine's signal(data) for every different node.
I am confused how to do that or how can server reads the signal from machines.

if I am defining Information model in XML and letting node manager create all the nodes with this resource(XML file) only, then does OPC UA server can map the machine's data with those nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now i need to write the server for the physical machine where i need to read the machine's signal(data) for every different node. I am confused how to do that or how can server reads the signal from machines.

This is its own problem and has nothing to do with OPC UA. You'd have to figure this out if the data was being accessed by any other means (REST API, etc...) as well.

The answer to this is going to be totally unique to your situation and dependent on whatever this machine is and what options it has available to consume data from it, if any.